# is it possible to retrieve google contacts informations in one with url Json or XML?

Tags: google-contacts-api

I have been able to retrieve little infos (mainly email and id ) in JSon using Oauth2 the url:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?&max-results=5&alt=json

Now I want more details like name/ phone number .  Is it possible in one call with one url ?

Thanks

Comment: works with :https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?&alt=json so I think adding max-result trunk the result  .

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using the google example code. The information you need is retrived by this url, part of the example code is wrong, it seems like the information is not retrived.
You'll find these stackoverflow links useful:

[Google Contacts API XML parsing with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443363/google-contacts-api-xml-parsing-with-php)

[Fetch Contacts from google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423622/fetch-contacts-from-google)